# How to go from DOM node to viewModel object?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

When the `drop` function is called back, `this` is set to the droppable DOM node (the target) and ui.draggable is the DOM node which was dragged.

Is there an idiomatic way of getting the model object which has been rendered as a particular DOM node?

(I'm using jQuery templates, if it matters.  There may be more than one rendering of a single modelView object.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this but I cheated. Here are my bindings.

**EDIT**

Since the below example was incomplete I have done a simple complete example which can be found here.

http://pastie.org/1446229

Where you store the currently dragging element is up to you. In the example I use a global variable as a proxy for the viewModel item. You could give each of your draggables and droppables a reference to their parent model and access the property this way, it's up to you.

Hope this helps.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.drag = {
                init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
                    var $element = $(element),
                        dragOptions = { 
                            revert: 'invalid',
                            revertDuration: 250,
                            cancel: 'span.handle',
                            cursorAt: { left: 28, bottom: 0 },
                            appendTo : 'body',
                            helper: function () { 
                                return $('<div class="drag-icon"><img src="images/folder-large.png" alt="move" width="32" height="32" /></div>'); 
                            },
                            cursor: "pointer",
                            addClasses: false,
                            distance: 10,
                            start : function (e, ui) { 
                                viewModel.isDragging();
                            }
                        };

                    $element.draggable(dragOptions);
                },
                update : function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
                    var $element = $(element),
                        active = valueAccessor();

                    if (!active) {
                        $element.draggable('disable');
                    }
                    else {
                        $element.draggable('enable');
                    }
                }
            };

ko.bindingHandlers.drop = {
                init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
                    var $element = $(element),
                        value = valueAccessor() || {},
                        handler = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value.onDropComplete),
                        dropOptions = { 
                            greedy: true,
                            tolerance: 'pointer',
                            addClasses: false,
                            drop: function (e, ui) {
                                setTimeout(function () { 
                                                handler(viewModel.dragging()); 
                                            }, 0);
                            }
                        };
                    $element.droppable(dropOptions);
                }
            };
```

So I setup draggable and in the start function I store the currently dragging node `viewModel.isDragging();` then I can access it again in the drop handler.

Cheers,

Ian

Comment: Thanks, that's useful but possibly incomplete.  How can you get the viewModel object which was used to render the droppable target?  I need both parts of this interaction - and ideally the 'nearest parent' viewModel object for any part of the DOM.

Comment: You have access to the item that was being dragged viewModel.dragging(). When a draggable is dropped on a drop target the "drop" handler runs. In this handler I have access to the viewModel that was bound or a property on it using valueAccessor(). The viewModel parameter passed into update/init is the item that it was bound to.

Comment: In fact maybe it isn't clear here but I am calling handler with the dropped model element. Handler is a method specified in the binding (onDropComplete), this is called on the viewModel that was bound as the drop target.

Comment: Can you give an example of the data structure you are rendering as drag and drop. I'll then update my example.

Comment: Edited to include a complete example.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at the example.

Comment: Have you encountered this bug, while doing work with draggables?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606655/jqueryui-auto-scroll-goes-double-distance-when-dragging

Comment: I haven't. That is strange. I thought it might be a doctype issue but it isn't. Stumped... How did the example work out for you?

Comment: Its seems to be related to the helper. If i set the helper to clone then it works also if i supply my own helper it works.

Comment: Great example! Worked well with knockout 2 once the jquery templates were replaced with knockoutjs templates. e.g. <li data-bind="drop : {}, html: name">