# jQueryUI - auto scroll goes double distance when dragging

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I've distilled the problem into the shortest page which exhibits the problem (apologies for inline style).

If you scroll down and drag the 'drag me' title, look how the dragged element zooms away from the cursor.  It seems to be moving double the distance (relative to the document) than it needs to.

I have reproduced the problem in IE8, FF3.5 and Chrome.  On WinXP and Ubuntu.

Am I doing something stupid in my code, or have I encountered a bug?

Thanks,

Chris.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".draggable").draggable();
        });    
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 100px; height: 800px; background: green;">
</div>
<h1 class="draggable">drag me</h1>
<div style="width: 100px; height: 800px; background: green;">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me you've found a bug :)
It works fine until the mouse cursor stays inside the visible area... then the H1 enable the hyperdrive :D
To reduce (but not to avoid completely) the bug's effects you can restrict the draggable area into e tag (eg. body) AND disable the scroll:

```
            $(".draggable").draggable();
            $(".draggable" ).draggable( "option", "containment",  'body' );
            $(".draggable" ).draggable(  "option", "scroll" , false  );
```

or an arbitrary area (other option in docs):

```
            var area=Array(0,740,300,880);
            $(".draggable").draggable();
            $(".draggable" ).draggable( "option", "containment",  area );
            $(".draggable" ).draggable(  "option", "scroll" , false  );
```

Comment: Yes, I observed that exact same behaviour, before scrolling.  Unfortunately, I need the scrolling effect, as not all drop targets may fit within the visible area.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions - I've now filed it as a bug.  http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6817  http://jsbin.com/uvodi3

Comment: It works for me if I set the helper to clone or supply my own helper as a function.